# What could be the reason for my program to take more time to come to main method?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to run the class, and it takes more than a minute to come to main() method.

I've imported around 140 jars, which is required to call my internal APIs. So, will it always takes more time, to load all the jars before coming to main method ?

Is it a way to minimize the execution time ?

This is how, my main class looks like, wherein I've imported most of the jars.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import com.thd.custom.util.XMLUtil;
import com.yantra.interop.japi.YIFApi;
import com.yantra.interop.japi.YIFClientFactory;
import com.yantra.ycp.core.YCPContext;
import com.yantra.yfc.dom.YFCDocument;
import com.yantra.yfc.dom.YFCElement;
import com.yantra.yfc.dom.YFCNodeList;
import com.yantra.yfs.core.YFSObject;

public class OrderStatCompUI extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static JTextField[] fields;
    private JXDatePicker[] datepicker;
    private static JCheckBox chkEcommOrder;
    private static JCheckBox chkStoreOrder;
    protected static JTable     tblOrdStatus;
    private JScrollPane     spOrdStat;
    protected static DefaultTableModel model;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> setColor = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    private ArrayList<String> transferOrderNo = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static JButton btnSlctRow;
    private static JButton btnAllRow;
    private JPanel btmPnl;
    private YCPContext env;
    private static JButton btnExport;
```

I've also tried to create 2 class, wherein main class, will have only UI part and other class has the behavior part. When I do so, main() method got executed, within a second, but when I do some action in the console, and when the execution goes to behavior class, it takes again a minute to load and populate the data.

Could anyone help me in this regard ?

Comment: Looks like it's time to *profile* the program during startup, to see where time is spent.

Comment: classloading takes time. Seems that you should continue to split your big class into smaller classes in order to avoid that the 140 jars are loaded at startup. Use `java -verbose:class` to see when the JVM loads a class

Comment: After using -verbose:class, I can see, which jar takes more time. And as you suggested, will try to split my class into smaller one. Thanks a lot for your comments, it really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the JVM to run in client mode which has much faster startup times. If it is running in server mode (possible if you have a system with big specs (memory etc) then the startup time is slower.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, but I didn't pass, any arguments to run in server mode. Below are the arguments, I'll pass to execute. **-Xms512m -Xmx768m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=256m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dvendor=shell  -DvendorFile=C:/Siva/WorkJars/servers_prod.properties -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8**

Comment: Then based on your input that when you split the class, the behaviour class code is taking a long time to execute, it appears that you have some logic in that class that is taking that time. To identify what is taking a long time to load suggest you put a debug point in your IDE in the beginning of your behaviour class and go line by line to see where is the call that is taking the maximum time.. Or put multiple debug points or add some loggers at appropriate places so that the time at that place is logged..